# vue-router cannot implement the two level routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to implement the two level routing by using vue-router

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Hello from '../components/Hello.vue'
import First from '../page/firstPage.vue'
import Login from '../page/logIn.vue'
import Second from '../page/secondPage.vue'

Vue.use(Router)


const routes =[
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/first',
    component: First,
    children: [ {
      path: 'hello',
      component: Hello
    }
    ]
  },
]
const router = new Router({
  mode:'history',
  routes:routes
})

export default router
```

But when I input  `http://localhost:8080/first/hello`, it returns the 'First' component not the 'Hello' component.

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have the `<router-view></router-view>` tag inside the First component?

Comment: I didn't code the router-view at the First component. I didn't know the children component should render the component which is its super routing component, so that it can show up.  Thank you

Comment: Every nested routes needs the router-view in the parent in order to be rendered, you can create a new route at the main level with path `/first/hello` instead